# Correction tag synonym: grammaticality [Correction tag burninated]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

[correction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/correction) has 74 questions and a majority of the questions seem to be intended to ask about grammaticality, *correctness* (not correction) and proof-reading for some phrases and sentences, for example:

Proof-reading:

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/359325/my-morning-text-revison

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/346279/sentence-structure-can-you-help-me-to-arrange-the-words-in-the-correct-order

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336937/is-this-sentence-correct

Grammaticality:

[Could you please tell me the answer and why?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/350094/could-you-please-tell-me-the-answers-and-why)

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332722/which-one-is-gramatically-correct-was-were

[Where does the [sic] go in this sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/331626/where-does-the-sic-go-in-this-sentence)

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315009/can-i-use-a-gerund-in-a-non-restrictive-clause

I can't list all the questions. Would it be OK to synonymize [correction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/correction) with [grammaticality](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality) since we don't allow proof-reading and there is no proof-reading tag?

I think it is more efficient than unnecessarily editing all the 74 questions just to remove the [correction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/correction). Thoughts, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My view is that [correction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/correction) is being used almost as a meta tag, rather like [homework](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework). It's not tagging questions *about* correction and the correction process, but tagging questions which ask *for* correction. In fact, I find it difficult to imagine on-topic questions *about* correction.

If that is indeed its primary use, it should be removed, not synonymised — and probably blacklisted.

(And yes, that will bump all those questions. But that effect is temporary.)

Comment: Blacklisting is incompatible with synonymising. Blacklisting requires input from SE staff, and they won't do it if the tag is still in use. It must be removed for blacklisting to happen.

Comment: @Rathony that's unlikely gonna happen.[Shog explains blacklisting here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239189/how-should-we-make-tag-blacklist-requests)

Comment: @Rathony technical feasibility does not seem to support your suggestion though: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242661/338924

Comment: @Rathony so what. That's still the status quo regarding tags. There is nothing that says they changed anything that I could find.

Comment: @Rathony There is no solution which does not involve bumping questions. In fact, bumping questions on tag edits is actually desirable (so that others can check the result is what is intended), and there have been questions and answers on Meta about that in the past. Blacklisted tags **cannot and must not** exist; and synonyms are a means of existing.

Comment: **@Everyone Please ensure comments on answers are relevant to the answer.**

Comment: @AndrewLeach I understand. But it seems that SE staff can mass-edit the tags without bumping the questions. I've not confirmed it yet. Also, what's wrong with leaving the "correction" tag? Many people come here to correct their sentences. I think the correction tag is very close to grammaticality and there are many questions under the grammaticality tag that are as useless as those under the correction tag. What I wonder is, is it worth removing and blacklisting the tag? If you think so, I will leave it at that and will not raise any issue. I just tried my best not to bump 74 questions.

Comment: I've started to burninate the correction tag, 5 posts today from the oldest and invited @Helmar to join me. I will edit around 5 posts every day (when I have time) to minimize the impact on the front page. Will let you know when it is done. You are welcome to join it.

Answer (score 5):

This would be a terrible idea. If we would make correction a *synonym* of *grammaticality* the auto-suggest shows the parent tag. We already set this unfortunate precedent with *correct* and *correctness*. Whenever anyone types correct in the tag field this shows up. Making the people believe they tread the same path as nearly 4k other users before.

[image]

Burnination would lead to this, a first road bump when creating shitty correction questions:

[image]

And subsequent blacklisting would lead to this for the persistent user:

[image]

Thus, the decision to synonymize would create the impression of 4k precedents while burninating and blacklisting has a serious chance of stopping such bad questions.